How do I justify unknown probabilities?
The probability of a dice landing on 6 5 times is 1/6^5. The probability of finding a rock that is shaped exactly like me purely by nature is unknown.
Yet I know for a fact that the latter should be more improbable. And I would say everyone would agree. But if I don’t know the probability, how do I justify this?

Perhaps there are more possible rock shapes than sequences of 5 dice rolls.

Indeed you could go out to witness the universally agreed exactly zero frequency of such a natural rock as a frequentist in a aleatorically constructive way, yet for a staunch Bayesian existentialist holding motto like 'existence precedes essence', the degree of belief about the existence of such a rock with a seemingly unexplainable low level much lesser than 1/6^5 yet not exactly zero essence exists in a preceding fashion since it cannot be proved absolutely impossible as epistemic uncertainty either a priori or a posteriori which only drives down its value arbitrarily small very likely...

You do not need to know the probability, or some other quantity for that matter, to know that it is less than some value. Values are always easier to estimate from above/below than to find exactly. The reason you know "for a fact" that finding your body-shaped rock is more improbable is that you encountered many rocks, none of them shaped like a body, and from that sampling the probability can be estimated from above.

We have no idea what the asker is shaped like. Maybe like a river pebble, piece of shale or chunk of granite? We need more info to begin to answer.

There's a nice concept called credence.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credence_(statistics)
Credence is the subjective degree of belief in a proposition. It's useful when we can't sensibly put an objective probability on an event, but we can make our best guess.
One way to look at it is to ask what gambling odds you would consider to be fair regarding a given proposition.
Credence follows the same mathematical rules as probability. For example if two propositions are independent then the credence of their conjunction is the product of their individual credences, and so forth.
But we need not make metaphysical assumptions about reality, as we do with probability. We all have subjective opinions and beliefs, and credence lets us assign numeric values to those without having to make assumptions about what's true or real. To assign a credence to a proposition, all we have to do is interrogate our own subjective degree of belief.
The Wiki page I linked has more info, as does SEP.
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/
In your rock example, you might set a credence of .000000001 or so of finding a rock that looks just like you. It's not an objective probability. It's just a subjective degree of belief, or the gambling odds that you would consider fair in order to take the bet.

Experience can be used to justify this, in many different ways.
Perhaps you have experience of seeing rocks. Even if you haven't seen 65 rocks in your life (that's only 7,776, so it's very possible you have!), you have seen a decent proportion of that number, and none of them were probably even similarly-shaped to yourself. If 1 in 7,776 rocks looked exactly like you, many more should look similar to you, based on your experience that rocks don't have drastically different shapes to each other. So your experience of seeing enough rocks, none of which look like you, tell you that this would be more improbable.
Perhaps you have experience of reading newspaper articles (or watching YouTube videos, etc.) about improbable events which have occurred. You might have seen some examples like "this cloud looks exactly like the virgin Mary", or so on, with a photo showing a cloud which does look quite like the virgin Mary. If the similarity in that case is notable enough to report, then it can't be a very common occurrence. On the other hand, "this man rolled five sixes in a row" doesn't match with your experience of things which were improbable enough that their occurrence was noteworthy. So, your experience of reports of improbable occurrences tells you that this would be more improbable.
Perhaps you have experience of seeing people, all of whom look different enough to tell them apart. If you have seen 7,776 people who all looked different, and you know there are many more people in the world, your experience justifies a belief that there are many more than 7,776 people who look different. So even if every rock looked exactly like some person, there would still be only a one in several billion chance that a given rock looked exactly like you in particular.
Note that none of these arguments justifies any belief that the probability of such an event is some particular number. Rather, they justify your belief that this probability is less than some other probability. It's usually a lot easier to compare two things and determine that one is less probable than the other, than it is to mathematically determine the exact probability of each event. But a comparison ─ that one probability is less than another ─ is all you have asked how to justify in this question.

"Ugly! Ugly bags of mostly water!" Maybe the asker looks like a crystal, in which case, sure, naturally occurring shape. We shouldn't make human-biased assumptions!


Yet I know for a fact that the latter should be more improbable. And I would say everyone would agree. But if I don’t know the probability

You have just identified one cognitive capacity of human beings, and more generally of all animals with a natural brain. Animals don't survive in the wild, or in human-built environment, by computing probabilities according to the Theory of Probabilities, yet they all need to be able to assess, not exactly, but sufficiently accurately, the probabilities of at least some near future events. Without this cognitive capacity, they wouldn't be able to decide what to do next, and they would just die within a short time (and they don't).

how do I justify this?

The probability that a rock be shaped exactly like you depends on the criterion to decide that it is, so I don't think that there is any definite answer to this, but it would in any case come down to the quantity of information involved given the criterion.
